# Dsum with Null Value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am having abit of a situation and hope you can point me at the right direction.

1st DSUM (Text2):

=DSum("[quantity_ya7]","Stock","[part_number]= '" & [part_number] & "'")

2nd DSUM (Text2): (This can be Null at times as there are no withdrawals or records)

=DSum("[amt_ya7]","Withdrawal","[part_number]= '" & [part_number] & "' ")

After setting the 2 DSUM above, I will carry the subtract out.

=Text1-Text2

If there are values for to calculate for 2nd DSUM, the result will display in order. Else, it will be empty. (No values displayed)

How do I calculate as -0 (deduct 0) so I can get the right value displayed?

Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: `=NZ(DSum("[amt_ya7]","Withdrawal","[part_number]= '" & [part_number] & "' "),0)` will return 0 if the DSUM returns NULL.  It can then be used in the calculation.

Comment: I was reading the link that stated NZ too but did not managed to do it successfully. (https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/189852-nz-assistance-dsum). Thank you for the help, much appreciated!!!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use the Nz function to return zero, a zero-length string ("
>   "), or another specified value when a Variant is Null. For example,
>   you can use this function to convert a Null value to another value and
>   prevent it from propagating through an expression.
>   https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c

In  your case you want the DSUM to return 0 rather than Null when there's no value so you can use it in a calculation.

`=NZ(DSum("[amt_ya7]","Withdrawal","[part_number]= '" & [part_number] & "' "),0)`